# Analytically continuing a function defined via an integral

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation, branch-cuts

Suppose we want to analytically extend a function $g(z)$ that is defined as an analytic function everywhere in the complex $z$ plane except the negative $z$ axis (for example, via an integral). Would its analytic extension always have some kind of poles or branch points on the negative $z$ axis? Is it possible that it continues to an analytic function? (Is there a way to argue for this using Liouville's theorem?)

As pointed out in a comment below there are some trivial examples that extend to analytic functions. The example I am interested in is the function $g(z)$ defined via the integral
$$g(z)=\int_0^{\infty}ds\ e^{-zs}f(s),$$

with $f(s)$ having poles or branch points on the imaginary $s$ axis (along with other properties required for the convergence of this integral). A [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Region_of_convergence) for Laplace transforms says this is holomorphic for $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0$. We can then vary the contour of integration between $\mathrm{arg}(s)\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to define a holomorphic function in the complex $z$ plane everywhere except the negative $z$ axis. Would the continuation of $g(z)$ to the entire complex $z$ plane then have poles or branch points on the negative $z$ axis?

Comment: Is your true question the general one in the first paragraph or the example in the second paragraph? As stated, the one in the first paragraph could have any answer because "defined" is extremely broad: for example, we can define a function from $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$ to be $0$ everywhere on that set, and that analytic function trivially has an analytic continution to an entire function.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good point. I was thinking of more complicated functions than that, so perhaps it is better to rephrase the second one as the true question.